# Create Object (in ViewSet class) with Celery Task in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-rest-viewsets

Hello I encountered a problem which i am not able to solve by myself. I tried to call function create_with_celery inside create but it didnt work

How should I call create.delay with proper arguments? 
I don't know how to properly call create function to make workers create objects

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    @app.task(bind=True)
    def create(self, request):
        article = Article.objects.create(link=request.data['link'])
        article.save()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)

        words = WordList(article.link)
        # take every 90nth word for faster loading only dev approach
        i = 0
        for word in range(0, len(words.list)):

            # try to take word from database
            i += 1
            try:
                existing_word = Word.objects.filter(name=words[word])
                Word.objects.create(
                    name=existing_word[0].name,
                    advance_level=existing_word[0].advance_level,
                    definition=existing_word[0].definition,
                    article=Article.objects.get(id=article.id)
                )
                print('word nr {}/{} "{}" created from database'.format(i,
                                                                        len(words.list), words[word]))

            except:
                # if it's not existing fetch data from web
                Word.objects.create(
                    name=words[word],
                    advance_level=get_word_frequency(words[word]),
                    definition=get_word_definition(words[word]),
                    article=Article.objects.get(id=article.id)
                )
                print('word nr {}/{} "{}" fetched from web'.format(i,
                                                                   len(words.list), words[word]))

        response = {'message': 'Article created ', 'result': serializer.data}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Im trying to do something like this but I get error "Object of type 'Article' is not JSON serializable"

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    @app.task(bind=True)
    def create_with_celery(self, article, serializer, words, req):
        i = 0
        for word in range(0, len(words.list)):
            # try to take word from database
            i += 1
            try:
                existing_word = Word.objects.filter(name=words[word])
                Word.objects.create(
                    name=existing_word[0].name,
                    advance_level=existing_word[0].advance_level,
                    definition=existing_word[0].definition,
                    article=Article.objects.get(id=article.id)
                )

                print('word nr {}/{} "{}" created from database'.format(i,
                                                                        len(words.list), words[word]))

            except:
                # if it's not existing fetch data from web
                Word.objects.create(
                    name=words[word],
                    advance_level=get_word_frequency(words[word]),
                    definition=get_word_definition(words[word]),
                    article=Article.objects.get(id=article.id)
                )
                print('word nr {}/{} "{}" fetched from web'.format(i,len(words.list), words[word]))


def create(self, request):
    article = Article.objects.create(link=request.data['link'])
    article.save()
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)
    words = WordList(article.link)
    req = request

    self.create_with_celery.delay(article, serializer, words, req)

    response = {'message': 'Article created ', 'result': serializer.data}
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Hey I'm having similar issue. Did you solve it? @Adrian Zyskowski

Comment: @YashaswiniBhat As someone mentioned below you can only pass basic JSON to celery. You can't pass directly ModelViewSet's create function to celery with Python objects as arguments (self, request).

Comment: You should have your celery tasks in tasks.py file and these tasks should only receive basic types arguments (int, string, etc..)

Comment: I will try to answer you directly if you create another question on stack :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass basic types supported in JSON.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea what would be a good implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Take in mind that celery is a good tool to process async data, as I see what you try to do on `ArticleViewSet`, you could achieve that directly on the save method of the `ArticleSerializer`.

Comment: You mean I can write the functions create and create_with_celery in serializers.py on ArticleSerializer?

Comment: Yes that is the idea, use the Serializers as you use django Forms, in the views should not be all that heavy logic.